# How to fill the area between a rotated curve and 2 horizontal lines?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a normal distribution curve and 2 straight lines at 2 different y values and I need to fill only the area between the three. I've been looking at `fill_between` and polygons but can't get either to work for me.

```
        #Probability plot
        final_prices.sort()
        price_mean = np.mean(final_prices)
        price_standard = np.std(final_prices)
        normalized_df = stats.norm.pdf(final_prices, price_mean, price_standard)
        ax2.tick_params(direction='in', length=6, width=2, colors=color_tick, right=True, labelright='on')
        ax2.plot(normalized_df, final_prices, color=color_line)

        ax2.set_xlim([min(normalized_df), max(normalized_df)])
        ax2.set_ylim([min(final_prices), max(final_prices)])
        ax2.invert_xaxis()

        #mean line
        probability_frame = pd.DataFrame(final_prices, normalized_df)
        mean_price = probability_frame.loc[max(normalized_df), :].iloc[0]
        # ax2.axhline(y = mean_value, color=color_midline, linestyle='--')

        #standard deviation lines
        sigma = statistics.pstdev(final_prices)
        sigma_up_one = mean_price + sigma
        sigma_down_one = mean_price - sigma

        ax2.axhline(y=(sigma_up_one), color=color_sigma, linestyle='-')
        ax2.axhline(y=(sigma_down_one), color=color_sigma, linestyle='-')
        ax2.axhline(y=(sigma_up_one + sigma), color=color_sigma2, linestyle='-')
        ax2.axhline(y=(sigma_down_one - sigma), color=color_sigma2, linestyle='-')

        ax2.set_xlabel('Probability')
        ax2.set_ylabel('Price')
        ax2.set_title('Price Probability Distribution ' + ticker, color=color_label)
        ax2.xaxis.label.set_color(color_label)
        ax2.yaxis.label.set_color(color_label)

        plt.tight_layout()
        plt.show()
```

Here is my current output.

[image]

I need to fill the area between the innermost lines that represent the 1st standard deviation from the mean but only up to the curve line. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`plt.fill_betweenx` can be used to fill the area between x=0 and the gauss curve. The `where=` parameter can limit the fill to the area between the y-values defined by the standard deviation.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from scipy import stats

price_mean = 216
price_standard = 19
final_prices = np.linspace(price_mean - 4*price_standard, price_mean + 4*price_standard, 200)

norm_prices = stats.norm.pdf(final_prices, price_mean, price_standard)
plt.plot(norm_prices, final_prices, color='crimson')
plt.axhline(price_mean - price_standard)
plt.axhline(price_mean + price_standard)

plt.fill_betweenx(final_prices, 0, norm_prices,
                        where=(final_prices >= price_mean - price_standard) & (final_prices <= price_mean + price_standard),
                        color='green', alpha=0.3)
plt.gca().invert_xaxis()
plt.xlim(xmax=0)
plt.show()
```

[image: example plot]

Comment: Thank you! I'm gonna name my kids after you!